# Syntax highlighting hints break revision diffs in editor's activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, revisions-list, diff

After adding language hints to various answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300149/bomb-dropping-algorithm), I discover that the affected code blocks are shown with all their whitespace collapsed in the rendered diffs in my activity tab... [and only there](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=activity):

[image]

On closer inspection it appears that the `<pre>` tags are missing from the second snippet, which is what's causing the whitespace to collapse.

The [revision history for the post depicted above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15303596/revisions) looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in the next build (and retroactively so, since those diffs aren't cached).

Getting the diff for the activity list accidentally Markdown-converted the post text twice. That's usually not an issue, since the Markdown conversion is mostly idempotent (and that's why, despite being broken for one and a half years, this has only been noticed now). When syntax highlighting hints come into play however, this idempotence is gone.

The first conversion adds the `class="lang-foo"` prettify information. The second conversion sees a `class` attribute on a `<pre>` tag, which the HTML sanitizer doesn't allow. And unlike in the first conversion, where we know that the `class` attribute was created by the conversion and thus is exempt, in the second conversion it looks like user-supplied, disallowed HTML, and hence the `<pre>` tag is removed by the sanitizer.